# Fab buttons on CoordinatorLayout under BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview

The fab buttons hide under the BottomNavigationView, I want them to be on top of the BottomNavigationView, I tried using a constraint layout but this broke some functionality. I need to keep the coordinatorLayout.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:maxImageSize="38dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/close_voice_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="getSpeechInput"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:maxImageSize="34dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/voice_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="getSpeechInput"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fabSize="auto"
        app:maxImageSize="34dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#D8D8D8"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfc9t.jpg

What can I do for the fabs to be on top of the bottomNavigationView, and if the bottomNavigationView goes hidden, these buttons should go on the bottom of the layout.

Comment: You can give the actual output? So that we can understand what exactly you want in the output.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Set elevation to your fab icons like this:

```xml
app:elevation="16dp"
```

Comment: I don't want my buttons to be literally over the bottonNavigationView, I want them to be on top of it. Here's a sketch (paint srry) : https://imgur.com/a/htM01kS